# knockout js two foreach loop with condition

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem regarding my 2 knockout foreach binding
i want to filter it per category.

heres the scenario

```
var categorySelected = {CategoryId, CategoryName, MeasureName}
var measureperCategoryData = {CategoryId, MeasureId, MeasureName}

    <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: categorySelected">
          <div class="headline">
                <h4 data-bind="text : $data.CategoryName"></h4>
              <div class="row" data-bind="foreach : $root.measureperCategoryData">
                    <label data-bind="text : $data.MeasureName, if : $parent.CategoryId == $data.CategoryId">                  </label>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your first problem is that isn't valid JavaScript. Please post actual, syntactically valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is knockout js the categorySelected and measureperCategoryData are observable array.
Actually i found out the reason why it didnt work because it compare the $data.CategoryId recognize as a function so i change it into $parent.CategoryId == $data.CategoryId().
This works.

Thanks Matt and PW for your response. :)